# Zooming up my created wallpaper after restart smartphone

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got a problem with wallpaper. When I create this and reset my Phone, wallpaper zomms up. How I can change BootReceiver class for loading correctly positions of wallpaer and screen?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static int toPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);

        Context context;
        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Podglad.class);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.IVimage1:
                toPhone = R.drawable.kwiaty;
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.IVimage2:
                toPhone = R.drawable.listek;
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.IVimage3:
                toPhone = R.drawable.kwiaty;
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Podglad:

```
public class Podglad extends ActionBarActivity {
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_podglad);

        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        View myView =  this.findViewById(R.id.a);
        myView.setBackgroundResource(MainActivity.toPhone);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("wallpaperapp", 0);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("position", 0).commit();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), MainActivity.toPhone);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap, width, height, true);
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(Podglad.this);
                wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.podglad, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

BootReceiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG="BootReceiver";

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
        try{
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("wallpaperapp",0);
            int position= sharedPreferences.getInt("position", 0);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),MainActivity.toPhone);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
            wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
            wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" and redo whatever you did to get it working in the first place.

Or you could resize and crop the image to fit the desired dimensions so that when the device reboots it loads an image that is the perfect size already.

There may be other solutions but those two came to mind first.

---

Edit, Here is an example of what I meant in the comments about using one method:

```
public class WallpaperUtil {
    public static setWallpaper(Context context) {
        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context
                                .getSharedPreferences("wallpaperapp",0);
            ...
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            ...
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
        WallpaperUtil.setWallpaper(getApplicationContext);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SetWallpaperActivity extends Activity
                                  implements View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonSetWallpaper:
                // save choice to SharedPreferences then
                WallpaperUtil.setWallpaper(this);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do it. I've created BrodcastReceiver class and added "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" It's not work. I wrote the same like this: http://pastebin.com/TTWsUq3S

Comment: Is your Receiver using the exact same method as your original action? By exact I mean the same method from the same class, not a copy-paste. Perhaps you made a typo in one?

Comment: The same class? Well, my onClick method has to be in BootReceiver class?

Comment: No, it doesn't _have_ to be the same method name. I was suggesting that you write only one method to set the wallpaper and call it from two places. If you know one implementation does work, why rewrite it somewhere else and introduce another place to maintain code and possible future bugs? Just use the same method again.

Comment: Sorry but i still don't understand. Should I in BootReceiver class write for example: onClick() and then this method started or what? "write only one method to set the wallpaper and call it from two places" Where I should wrrite this method and call from?

Comment: Ok But if I want to change my project I have many red underlines in SharedPreferences. I'll paste you my code i edit, ok?

Comment: I wrote my code. Can you say me, what I should do with my code?

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. StackOverflow is not a free debugging service. Learn how to debug your code, read errors and exceptions and if you have a _specific_ problem return here and ask a new question. Alternatively you could edit this question to be clearer and more precise. I am not going to import and fix your whole project for you.

Comment: Ok I understood. My question is: how to run code of OnClick in BootReview class?

Comment: My sample code shows you how to do this. If you cannot follow the code you need to brush up on your Java/Android skills before attempting to make an app of this size.